# MySQL get intersection of multiple raws

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have table( `recipe_categories` ) structure as below

```
recipe_id   sub_category_id
1           2
1           3
1           5
2           3
2           5
3           2
3           5
```

I am getting `sub_category_id` from API (it is comma separated) and I want `recipe_id` which has all given sub_category_id

Example :
1) if user pass `sub_category_id` 3,5 in API
So recipe id 1 and 2 have sub_category_id 3 and 5
here `recipe_id` 3 will ignored as it has only `sub_category_id` 5 not 3
so result is `recipe_id` 1 and 2

2) if user pass `sub_category_id` 2,3,5
so the result is only `recipe_id` 1

With PHP I tried to explode ids  and created MySQL query as below and it is working :

```
 SELECT * FROM 
      ( SELECT *,GROUP_CONCAT(sub_category_id) as
      subcat FROM `recipe_categories` group by recipe_id
      ORDER BY `id` DESC )
    as a where find_in_set('5',subcat)
    and find_in_set('6',subcat) and find_in_set('7',subcat)
```

Here, using for loop I have made multiple find_in_set

So my question is, is there any better way that I can find the expected result directly from MySQL query without creating a query using PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this in a generic way (only requiring passing the comma separated string as a parameter) by counting the number of matching `sub_category_id` (using `FIND_IN_SET` to find them) and comparing that with the number of values in the string (which can be determined by subtracting the length with commas removed from the original length):

```
SELECT recipe_id
FROM recipe_categories
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(sub_category_id, '2,3,5')
GROUP BY recipe_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sub_category_id) = LENGTH('2,3,5') - LENGTH(REPLACE('2,3,5', ',', '')) + 1
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
recipe_id
1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f7ea80f6422e9fe5edf7ec8d4717750f)

Comment: Thanks @Nick,  so if it is 3,5 or 2,3,5 no need of any PHP code, right?

Comment: @YasinPatel exactly, just pass the string in the 3 places. See the updated demo with both examples: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4bc46334d78b46725aa76e9b0962877e

Answer (score 3):

Here is a canonical way of handling your requirement:

```
SELECT recipe_id
FROM recipe_categories
WHERE sub_category_id IN (3, 5)
GROUP BY recipe_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sub_category_id) = 2;
```

You may need to do some additional work to implement this from PHP using a prepared statement.

Comment: Thanks buddy, So  if my sub_category_id has 2,3,5 so last one is : HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sub_category_id) = 3; ?

Comment: Thanks buddy for help :) Your answer is working but Accepted @Nick answer as it is more dynamic and no need of PHP code. Upvating you answer :)